# Securing/restricting process permissions without using root

Tags: linux, security

I have 2 processes, a webserver and a daemon. The daemon generates html files that is used by the webserver. But for security reasons, the webserver must **not** have the same system level access as daemon: for the daemon uses sensitive files to generate said html files. Or to put it in a more logical approach to stating this restriction.

```
 - webserver can access html files.
 - daemon can access html files.
 - webserver cannot access sensitive files.
 - daemon can access sensitive files
```

So obviously, the easiest answer would be (1) to create 2 users, (2) set the permissions here and there, and (3) start the webserver as one user and the daemon as the other.

But I'm trying to figure out how to do (3) without the use of `root` (for even tighter security). **I want to be able to start the two processes as a non-root user while obeying the above restrictions.**